Angular 17 auxiliary route
I am trying to configure auxiliary route in Angular 17 but have some issue most likely due to the change to standalone components. Here is my configuration:
export const FEATURE_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ContactComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        redirectTo: 'contact',
      },
      {
        path: 'education',
        component: EducationComponent,
        // loadComponent: () =>
        //   import('./modules/education/education.component').then(
        //     (c) => c.EducationComponent
        //   ),
        outlet: 'modal',
      },
    ],
  },
];


export const routes: Routes = [{path: 'contact',loadChildren: () =>import('./feature.routes').then((r) => r.FEATURE_ROUTES),},{path: 'skills',outlet: 'modal',loadComponent: () =>import('./modules/skills/skills.component').then((s) => s.SkillsComponent),},];


routes config is imported in the main.ts according to the new Angular approach.
// app.component.html
<button (click)="navigateToContact()">Open contact</button>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<div class="modal-outlet">
  <router-outlet name="modal"></router-outlet>

Navigate to contact page works fine
  public navigateToContact(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['contact']);
  }

//contact.component.html
<button (click)="loadEducation()">Load educations</button>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="test"></router-outlet>

And the loadEducation method:
  public loadEducation(): void {
    this.router.navigate([
      '/',
      { outlets: { modal: ['contact', 'education'] } },
    ]);
    // this.router.navigate(['contact/education']);
  }

What I would like to achieve is working url: http://localhost:4200/contact(modal:education). Thanks
I am getting the following error: Error: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'contact/education'

The way to navigate to auxiliary route for EducationComponent should be:
public loadEducation(): void {
  this.router.navigate(['contact', { outlets: { modal: ['education'] } }]);
}

Hence, the URL will be:
/contact(modal:education)

Demo @ StackBlitz
